# If any subset of a set has zero measure, then the set has zero measure?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $A\subset\Bbb{R}$. I already proved that if $A$ has zero measure, then every proper subset $B\subset A$ has zero measure.
My question is if the reciprocal proposition holds.
I would be like: If every subset $B\subset A$ has zero measure, then $A$ has zero measure.
(I think maybe it holds, but I couldn't think a good proof).
I want to use this to prove that if $m^*(A)>0$, then exists a subset $B\subset A$ such that $m^*(B)>0$, where $m^*$ is the Lebesgue outer measure.
My definition of $A$ having zero measure means that , for every $\varepsilon>0$ exists a denumerable collection of closed intervals such that the collection covers $A$ and the sum of all the lengths of the closed intervals if less than $\varepsilon$.

Comment: Hint: Measure is countably additive, and a singleton has measure 0.

Comment: I assume you mean every strict subset otherwise the answer is fairly trivial :P

Comment: Just a subtlety (likely about notation): Not necessarily every subset $B \subseteq A$ has zero measure as those don't have to be measurable.

Comment: @QiZhu The **assumption** on $A$ is exactly that all (proper) subsets of $A$ have measure $0$. This does not imply that that subset is measurable always.

Comment: Are you considering any measure? If so, consider the counting measure in $\mathbb{R}$  and consider  $A=\{ 0 \} $. Any proper subset of $A$ is the empty set and so has measure 0, but $A$ has measure 1.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma I was talking about the first part of the OP‘s post, sorry if that was unclear from my comment.

Answer (score 2):

Any set $A$ is a subset of itself, so this holds. If you rephrase to ask about proper subsets, take $A \setminus \{*\}$ and use subadditivity. A similar result holds in any measure space (or outer measure) where points have 0 measure.